# Dynamic GraphQLObjectType

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to create a dynamic GraphQLObjectType with graphQl, something like this:

```
export const Project = (data) => {
  return new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Project',
    fields: () => ({
      id: {
        type: GraphQLString
      },
      type: {
        type: GraphQLString
      },
      author: {
        type: User,
        resolve: (root, args, req) => {
          ...
        }
      }
    })
  })
};
```

I call this model on my query in this way:

```
getProjectById: {
    type: Project(structure),
    args: {
      id: { type: GraphQLString }
    },
    resolve(source, args, req) {
      const projectService = new ProjectService(req);
      return projectService.getProjectById(args.id)
    }
  }
```

the problem is that doing this I get this error:

> Schema must contain unique named types but contains multiple types
>   named "Project"

where is the error? do you have some advice? many thanks

Comment: Try to return Project as an object not a function, because for each call you create a new instance but it should be instantiated only once. If you want to pass any data use arguments of resolvers.

Answer (score 1):

The call `Project(structure)` in turn calls `new GraphQLObjectType({name: 'Project',...})` . If you invoke `Project(structure)` more than once, you try to declare multiple GraphQLObjectTypes with the same name (which makes no sense).

If you would create/declare `GraphQLObjectType` dynamically, you have to generate a unique name property. E.g. like this:

`` // assuming data.name is unique 
export const Project = (data) => {
  return new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: `Project${data.name}`,
    ...
  })
} ``

Comment: yep, it was something like this....as I need the same name I'm pasing an instance instead of run the function everytime...thanks!

Comment: edit: I get back the error when I try to do the same thing on mutation, I think because I run the function again for mutation...but this shouldn't be a problem because with or without the function for muntation I should call another time the file and this should create a new instance....I'm doing something wrong?